# Pytorch: ValueError: Too many dimensions: 3 > 2. 9/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)

Tags: python, random, pytorch, mnist

I am using MNIST data to run my python using pytorch. I like to train only partial data for digits 0 and 1.  when I try to print the size of the first image it runs into this error:

> ValueError: too many dimensions: 3 > 2

I am very new to Python. The program runs fine if I don't segment the training data. Here is the code snippet

```
subset_indices = ((train_data.train_labels == 0) + (train_data.train_labels == 1)).nonzero()
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_data,batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False,sampler=SubsetRandomSampler(subset_indices))
```

Comment: here is the loop that's failing with value error - for i,(images,labels)in enumerate(train_loader):
    print(i,images.size(),len(labels))
    break

Comment: Full Trace : ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-ed217788eb5c> in <module>
----> 1 for i,(images,labels)in enumerate(train_loader):
      2     print(i,images.size(),len(labels))
      3     break
      4 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)

Comment: ---> 94         img = Image.fromarray(img.numpy(), mode='L')
     95 
     96         if self.transform is not None:

/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in fromarray(obj, mode)
   2690         ndmax = 4
   2691     if ndim > ndmax:
-> 2692         raise ValueError("Too many dimensions: %d > %d." % (ndim, ndmax))
   2693 
   2694     size = shape[1], shape[0]

ValueError: Too many dimensions: 3 > 2.

Comment: update your question and add it into there it will be more readable there.

Answer (score 1):

The indices just need to be in a 1D array which can be done using `.view(-1)`

For example
`sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(subset_indices.view(-1))`

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that you are passing a 3 dimensional array into the function `Image.fromarray` which is likely set in the wrong mode. You need to make sure `mode` is set to `RGB` so that it looks like `Image.fromarray(data, mode='RGB')`.